# Axios GET request and running web server

Tags: javascript, get, axios

I am trying to get an Axios GET request to work while web server is running, but whenever I use this code:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:8020/posts', {
        title: title.value,
        content: content.value
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
    });
    displayPost();
} 

async function displayPost() {
    console.log("click");
    await axios.get('http://localhost:8020/posts')
        .try(function (response){
            console.log(response);
            postContainer.innerHTML = "";
            for(let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                postContainer.innerHTML += `<p>${response.data[i].title}</p>
                                            <p>${response.data[i].content}</p>`;
            }
            console.log(response);
        })
```

I get an error message in the console saying axios.get(...).try is not a function at displayPost and HTMLInputElement.deletePost. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Axios doesn't have `try` method.

Comment: Typo: you probably meant `then`  like the previous block.

Answer (score -1):

Because there is no `try` function, I think it must be `axios.get().then()`. If you use this, there is no need `await` at the beginning. And if you use `await`, it must be `const resposnse = await axios.get()`

Answer (score -1):

> axios.get('url').then(res => {  // your code.. })